# {"ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"} - Update Last Number Sequence Oracle Database

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to update last number of sequence in database oracle using textbox on C#. When I tried to execute my program, I have got the error message **{"ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"}**
I am trying to rectify this problem, but I did not find how to fix it. I am new in #C and Oracle Database. Does anyone here could help me to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance
Here is my code

```
private void IDHEADER()
    {
        var result7 = new StringBuilder();
        using (var connectio1n = new OracleConnection(@"Data Source=mcf;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=tmci38001;Password=tmci38001;"))
        {
            string CommandText2 = "SELECT LAST_NUMBER FROM USER_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER'";
            OracleCommand command2 = new OracleCommand(CommandText2, connectio1n);
            connectio1n.Open();
            using (OracleDataReader dr = command2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    String a = dr[0].ToString();
                    ID_HEADER.Text = a;

                }
            }
        }
    }
private void btnUpd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Update Sequence ?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID_HEADER.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill in all necessary fields",
                                 "Incomplete Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                     MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
        String HEADER = ID_HEADER.Text.Trim();
OracleConnection db = new OracleConnection("Data Source=mcf;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=tmci38001;Password=tmci38001;");
db.Open();
OracleCommand cmd8 = new OracleCommand("ALTER SEQUENCE TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER INCREMENT BY LPAD(TO_NUMBER(:HEADER),0); SELECT TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; ALTER SEQUENCE TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER INCREMENT BY 1 ", db);

          cmd8.BindByName = true;
          cmd8.Parameters.Add(":HEADER", HEADER);
          OracleDataReader oraReader8 = null;
          oraReader8 = cmd8.ExecuteReader();
          oraReader8.Close();
          db.Close();
          db.Dispose();
          IDHEADER();
          Cursor = Cursors.Default;
          MessageBox.Show("BC Sequence Successfully updated...");
            }
        }
    }
```

As additional information, the error line thrown in **oraReader8 = cmd8.ExecuteReader();**

Comment: In which line the error thrown? I suspected the error thrown in `ExecuteReader()` but not sure which query that throws it.

Comment: Yeah, the error line thrown in oraReader8 = cmd8.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Are you tried to run the second query (`ALTER SEQUENCE ...`) in Oracle query editor by replacing parameter name with a value? If it runs perfectly, then the parameter name becomes the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to execute the 2nd query also in order to the last number that has been settled can be set automatic increment by 1

Comment: Please check this link for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375288/ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number-when-running-query-through-c-sharp

Comment: So you're implying that the query worked perfectly in Oracle SQL editor without the parameter, right? Then you should try remove the colon from parameter name in `Parameters.Add()`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : I've tried to remove the column from parameter name in Parameters.Add but it did not work

Comment: Since you have multiple statements, try give a shot to wrap query contents inside `BEGIN ... END;` block, .e.g. `BEGIN ALTER SEQUENCE ... END;`. Probably your query treated as anonymous block.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : I've tried and I've got the new error message like this {"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00103: Encountered the symbol \"ALTER\" when expecting one of the following:\n\n   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma\n   raise return select update while with <an identifier>\n   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<\n   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback\n   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge"}

Answer (score 0):

Since your query has multiple statements (2 `ALTER` statements and 1 `SELECT` statement) which should be executed at once, you must wrap them inside anonymous block and use `OPEN ... FOR` before `ALTER` statements like this:

```
OracleCommand cmd8 = new OracleCommand(@"BEGIN
                     OPEN :1 FOR ALTER SEQUENCE TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER INCREMENT BY LPAD(TO_NUMBER(:HEADER),0); 
                     SELECT TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; 
                     OPEN :2 FOR ALTER SEQUENCE TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER INCREMENT BY 1;
                     END;", db);
```

If the query above does not work, use [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) for `ALTER` statements and concatenate the parameter value, because you cannot execute DDL statements (`CREATE`, `ALTER` or `DROP`) as static SQL inside a block:

```
OracleCommand cmd8 = new OracleCommand(@"BEGIN
                     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER INCREMENT BY LPAD(TO_NUMBER(' || :HEADER || '),0)'; 
                     SELECT TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; 
                     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE TMCI_SEQ_BC_AJU_HEADER INCREMENT BY 1';
                     END;", db);
```

Then use parameter name without colon (`:`) prefix in `OracleCommand.Parameters`:

```
// standard
cmd8.Parameters.Add("HEADER", HEADER);

// alternative
cmd8.Parameters.AddWithValue("HEADER", HEADER);
```

As a last resort, if the solutions above doesn't work, use each statement inside `OracleCommand` separately with this condition:

1) `ALTER` statements must use `ExecuteNonQuery()`

2) `SELECT` statement must use `ExecuteReader()`

Related issues:

[How to execute multiple SQL statements in Oracle?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2366994)

[Getting error while trying to alter table in an sql block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575887/getting-error-while-trying-to-alter-table-in-an-sql-block)